# Calling application view from iframe tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, sapui5

I have created an application using shell control which contains three views. I am calling another application in shell application using `iframe` tag. Now I want to call one of the views of the shell application inside my `iframe` application.

How to achieve this, please help?

Comment: what is a shell application? and a shell control?

Comment: I think SO is offtopic for this kind of question, please try to ask in http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Shell control is a sapui5 control that i have used. it is a standard ux3 control of sapui5. And the application that i have created in which i am calling another application using iframe isthe shell application. I am referring to it as shell application, and it is not something standard.